# Finding RC time constant with a Y connection

Tags: circuit-analysis

I think I have somewhat of a solution to the problem pictured, but I'm not confident in it. What I did was treat the resistor as a load, so I removed it and found the equivalent capacitance of the circuit it was attached to, so I got a time constant of about 10.3ms. Is that right or am I oversimplifying? I'm not sure if I have to do that delta-y stuff (and I'm hoping that I don't).

[image: RC circuit]

Comment: This question makes not sense.  *What* problem?  Equivalent capacitance from *where* to *where*?  Even more baffling, how could you not see for yourself such basic information is missing?

Comment: Jeez man. I changed the title. That's what I'm trying to figure out. I'm trying to find the equivalent capacitance seen by the resistor.

Comment: I would say move the resistance in // with the 12-µF cap and you'll see that this resistance "sees" the 12-µF cap. in // with the series connection of the 6-µF plus the 5 µF//7 µF. The time constant is the resistance times this equivalent cap.

Comment: @TaylorDavison I know you're new here but Olin is like our angry grandfather :) he means well and just wants the best for this website. If you get chewed out by him it probably means you haven't explained yourself enough to receive help.

Comment: Gee-whiz. If you want the time-constant of this circuit omit the resistor and look at the simple series/parallel combinations of capacitors to get the *real* capacitance that is across the resistor. From there it is 2pi*RC.

Answer (score 1):

I get a very different number for the time constant, so I don't think you figured the capacitance across the resistor correctly.

The trick to this problem is to redraw it with a logical layout before doing anything else.  Then you just combine parallel and series combinations of capacitors.

Note that one of the capacitors is directly across the resistor.  The total equivalent capacitance can't be any less than that.  Two other capacitors are in parallel, so they just add.

Again, start by redrawing with a logical layout.  Leave the resistor where it is, and draw horizontal lines to the right from its top and bottom leads.  Now fill in the capacitors, drawing them all vertically.  Connect appropriately.  It shouldn't take more than 10 seconds with a calculator to find the total capacitance.

Comment: It just took a little redrawing for me to realize the obvious - the 5uF and 7uF are in parallel. Assuming I haven't made another mistake, is the total capacitance 16uF, and the time constant 48ms?

Comment: @Taylor: Yes --